# But which Lord of the Rings movies are they talking about?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

I'm looking at SO's [10 millionth question page](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) and I had a question about one thing:

> If a dev found a solution just half of those times, and it saved them just 30 minutes, that's nearly 1.85 billion hours saved.
>
> That's enough work hours to build 250 Empire State Buildings, or 170 Burj Khalifas.
> It's enough to read all of Wikipedia. 12,000 times.
> **Or watch all the Lord of the Rings movies** - with those interminable Hobbit ones - 92.5 million times.

Question is: extended edition or original theatrical release version?  This is *important*.

Comment: I prefer extended as well, but that's not really the question. This is *important*.

Comment: This question is *clearly* offtopic here and should be migrated to sci fi SE /s

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Extended would be almost 2 billion. (21 hours for the marathon, giving a total of 1.943 billion) source:https://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/2nauzj/movie_marathon_length/cmc4o83

Would have to say this is Normal versions =]

Comment: The individual that chose to use the theatrical version should be ashamed of themselves.

Answer (score 7):

Extended Edition. Always the Extended Edition.